# Jetpack JavaScriptSandbox blocks forever

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I am trying to run js code asynchronously using the Jetpack JavaScriptSandbox library, and it the docs it says to run `JavaScriptSandbox.createConnectedInstanceAsync(context).get()`.
The first part returns a `ListenableFuture<JavaScriptSandbox>` and with the `.get()` part you get the actual JavaScriptSandbox connection. Now, for some reason, the `.get()` part blocks forever on my device.

Is there anything extra I need to look for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> `get()` makes the UI thread wait for the Future to be resolved while the resolution is supposed to happen on the UI thread.

> you can try to either call get() on a background thread or use Async APIs provided by the Future class.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/290254837#comment4

can use callback temporarily.

```
ListenableFuture<JavaScriptSandbox> jsSandboxFuture =
        JavaScriptSandbox.createConnectedInstanceAsync(context);

Futures.addCallback(jsSandboxFuture, new FutureCallback<>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@Nullable JavaScriptSandbox jsSandbox) {
        sandbox = new WeakReference<>(jsSandbox);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {
        // ...
    }
}, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
```

use this in init method. And use `realSandBox.createIsolate();` in other part.